# Closed captioning not working in DAI

Tags: android, android-tv, google-ima, imasdk

Closed caption is not working/displaying in DAI sample which i get from [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-android-dai) 
Where as same assets key working fine and showing closed caption for platforms (i.e. AppleTV and Roku). I have used latest version (3.8)

Comment: Could you provide the logs?